# Magento 1.9 site not generating Captcha on customer registration form

Tags: security, magento, admin, captcha, spam

I currently working on a Magento 1.9 site using the Ultimo theme and we've been getting a number of users register recently which, based on the information received, we believe to be spam.

To help counter this I am trying to add a Captcha image to the customer registration form but although the Captcha is appearing on the login, it is NOT appearing on the customer registration form as can be seen below:

[image]

The settings I have used to set up the Captcha are below

[image]

I have checked in the developer tools and the captcha is not in the main HTML so not just a case of being set to display none in the CSS and there are no javascript errors in the console.

Also in the pathway:
httpdocs > app > design > frontend > rwd > default > layout

I heard the the captcha.xml could cause issues so I changed the filename to captcha-disabled.xml

Non of this has resolved the issue so I would be most appreciative for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do this now. Inside the captcha.xml there is a piece of code:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <!-- Remove all captcha functionality from theme layout -->
</layout>
```

...which I have written out, this has resolved the issue